# How to avoid custom column in search collection filter?

Tags: magento2, search, magento2.2.3

How to avoid custom column in search collection filter?
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'show_in_custom_assistance' in 'where clause',

```
  $collection = $this->_autoSearchCollection->create();
    $collection->setVisibility($this->_catalogProductVisibility->getVisibleInCatalogIds());
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->setStoreToFilter($storeid)
    ->addStoreFilter($storeid)
    ->addSearchFilter($search_arr)
    ->addMinimalPrice()
    ->addUrlRewrite()
    ->addTaxPercents();
    $collection->addCategoryFilter($category);
    // echo $collection->getSelect();

    return $collection;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use below code to remove either field or any attribute from your custom collection.

**To remove attribute :**

```
$collection->removeAttributeToSelect('show_in_custom_assistance');
```

**To remove field/table column :**

```
$collection->removeFieldFromSelect('show_in_custom_assistance');
```

Hope this help to you.

Thanks,

Comment: I was looking for this solution, but this has not worked for me. still coming in Where clause condition.

Comment: I want to remove the field from where the condition

Comment: You don't need to write this field in where clause if you want to remove it from the 
collection. Magento2 has already used this and you can check in these files for your reference : 1) vendor/magento/module-ui/DataProvider/AbstractDataProvider.php, 2) vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Collection.php

Comment: Thanks, Pratik Got the solution.

Comment: That's great to hear!